# Finding a TypeDeclaration in an IProject with the JDT search engine by its name

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

How can I find a `TypeDeclaration` in an `IProject` with the JDT search engine?
I want to use the package and the name (e.g. `"my.package.ClassName"`) of a class to find its `TypeDeclaration` in a specific `IProject`.

I know I could use the Java AST and a AST visitor which compares the current package and the node name, but I would prefer to use a string search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already hold the qualified name of the class and have a project, there's no need to employ the search engine.

Step 1: get an instance of `IJavaProject` representing your project:

```
IJavaProject jProj = JavaCore.create(proj);
```

Step 2: find the `IType` representing your class:

```
IType type = jProj.findType(fullyQualifiedname);
```

Step 3: get the containing compilation unit:

```
ICompilationUnit cu = type.getCompilationUnit();
```

Step 4: pass this to the `ASTParser` that will create your `TypeDeclaration` (as part of a `CompilationUnit`):

```
astParser.setSource(cu);
```

*(This assumes you already have an `ASTParser`, know how to invoke parsing and inspect the resulting AST).*